# Show data from 2 different dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am really new in sql query and i have 1 question. Below are the details:

I have ONE tables:

user_table

```
user_id username    balance   date_updated
------------------------------------------
1       adam        100       09/10/2017
2       david       100       09/10/2017
1       adam        110       10/10/2017
2       david       120       10/10/2017
1       adam        100       11/10/2017
2       david       100       11/10/2017
1       adam        110       12/10/2017
2       david       120       12/10/2017
```

I want to get the balance for the date of 9/10/2017 and 12/10/2017

expected result:

```
username    first_date   second_date
------------------------------------
adam        100          110
david       100          120
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the datatype of your `date_updated` field ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Aggregation

```
SELECT 
  username, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN date_updated = '2017-10-09' THEN balance END) AS first_date, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN date_updated = '2017-10-12' THEN balance END) AS second_date
FROM user_table 
GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when  with aggregate function

```
select username,
sum(case when date_updated='9/10/2017' then balance else 0 end) as first_date,
sum(case when date_updated='12/10/2017' then balance else 0 end) as second_date
from user_table t
group by username
```

I prefer here `sum()` instead `max()` because if more rows available for a user on particular date sum will cover